# Re-layout visible cells after asynchronous layout change

Tags: ios, autolayout, tableview

I have a UITableViewController with a collection of cells that I layout with auto layout. I set the rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension, estimatedRowHeight to 96, and set up the constraints for the cell so that the bottom constraint has a priority of 999. Everything works fine when all of the information to layout the cell is available in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

However, we're now trying to fetch the cards images asynchronously and won't know how big they are until they finish downloading from the server. Right now, in the completion handler for downloading the image, I'm updating the image view's height constraint's constant, and calling layoutIfNeeded() on the cell. This works perfectly if the cell is offscreen, or scrolls offscreen and then back onscreen. But if the cell was onscreen when the image started loading, it won't layout the cell again until it scrolls away and back.

How can I trigger these cells to layout again in a performant way? I've tried calling reloadRowsAtIndexPaths and layoutSubviews on the tableview but these both lagged a lot.

Comment: The `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` is generally the way to tackle this and it is very performant (unless you don't do it on the main queue). Perhaps you can clarify or give us a [minimal, yet complete and reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the tip - as I was calling reloadRowsAtIndexPaths from a completion handler it's very possible that it was happening on a background thread, hence the sluggish behavior. I will try to dispatch it back onto the main queue and possibly batch the reload rows calls, though it's only ever 3-4 cells that are visible so that may be unnecessary. I'm away from my computer at the moment but I will try that out the next chance I get.